# Is there a mechanism that automatically created an enumeration with the name of the entity fields?

Tags: java

Is there a mechanism that automatically created an enumeration with the name of the entity fields?

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuditEventGridDataRow {
    private String vendor;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    public enum ColName {
        vendor("vendor");

        @Getter
        private final String fieldName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could reasonably simply build this with your own annotation processor (similar to what Lombok does, but standardized, fewer capabilities, but generating additional sources is what it does best).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Reflection API permits inspecting fields and methods at runtime, generating additional code from existing declarations would require a compiler plugin (such as an annotation processor, like Lombok is). Alternatively, a separate build step could generate the sources for the enum before compilation.

I know of no existing annotation processor or code generator that creates such an enum.

Comment: Minor note: Lombok is not *just* an annotation processor. Specifically the ability to change the class that's annotated itself is not present in the standardized annotation processor API, so Lombok hot-patches itself into the compiler to achieve  that.